# Spring OAuth2RestTemplate throwing error NoSuchMethodError: Jackson databind

Tags: spring, spring-security, jackson

I updated my spring version to 5.2.22.RELEASE and all the fasterxml.jackson packages to 2.13.3.

Now when I hit a OAuth2RestTemplate method is get the following error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleSecondaryContextualization(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/BeanProperty;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer;
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.deser.WrapperHandlingDeserializer.createContextual(WrapperHandlingDeserializer.java:64)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handlePrimaryContextualization(DeserializationContext.java:825)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:550)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.DelegatingDeserializer.resolve(DelegatingDeserializer.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:294)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findNonContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:632)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:539)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.DelegatingDeserializer.resolve(DelegatingDeserializer.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:294)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.hasValueDeserializerFor(DeserializerCache.java:191)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.hasValueDeserializerFor(DeserializationContext.java:587)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.canDeserialize(ObjectMapper.java:3467)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.canRead(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:181)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.canRead(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:171)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$AcceptHeaderRequestCallback.canReadResponse(RestTemplate.java:864)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$AcceptHeaderRequestCallback.lambda$doWithRequest$0(RestTemplate.java:849)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:176)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$AcceptHeaderRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:853)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:735)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.doExecute(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:313)
    at com.test.total.loss.lien.service.impl.DocumentServiceImpl.getInsuranceDetails(DocumentServiceImpl.java:352)
    at com.test.total.loss.lien.service.impl.DocumentServiceImpl.getTemplateLienRequest(DocumentServiceImpl.java:310)
    at com.test.lien.controller.LoGUploadController.getTemplateLienRequest(LoGUploadController.java:157)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1043)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:295)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:353)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:82)
    at com.test.lien.filter.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:19)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:82)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3869)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3832)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:344)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.processSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2505)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2354)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2329)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2307)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1769)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1723)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:651)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)
> 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException
```

How can I resolve this? I have tried various permutation and combination with the Spring and Jackson versions.

I do not see this issue when the Spring version is 4.2.1.RELEASE and Jackson is 2.8.3

Comment: 99% of all `NoSuchMethodError`error are due to the usage of incompatible versions. This is the EXACT reason to why you should be using the `spring-boot-starter-parent` and not set library versions manually https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-starter-parent or as spring writes `The spring-boot-starter-parent is a special starter that provides useful Maven defaults. It also provides a dependency-management section so that you can omit version tags for “blessed” dependencies` so dont set manual dependency versions and use the parent

Comment: `OAuth2RestTemplate` is trying to call the function `handleSecondaryContextualization` which if you look in the API wasn't implemented in jackson-databind until version 2.5 https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationContext.html using the spring starter parent is the first thing covered in the getting started with spring section in the official documentation.

Comment: @Toerktumlare thank you for the response. But the Jacson-Databind version 2.13.3 so I believe the `handleSecondaryContextualization` should be available. 
This codebase is a bit old (~3 years) and it would be difficult for me now to introduce spring-boot-starter-parent.

Comment: You think it should be available? Well you can think as much as you want because thats what your error is telling us. 3 years is not old, the starter parent has been around for about 10 years. So the application was built using bad practices from the start by someone that didnt bother to learn spring